# I want to display information about my bitcoin node on a webpage (php or html)

Tags: php

I want to show information about my bitcoin node on a website.. how can I do this with windows + php + html + javascript + rpc?

I want something like that but with more information and perhaps more dynamic:

Example page:   `http://199.58.210.124/`

Comment: This could be a good place to start: http://jsonrpcphp.org/

Answer (score 1):

The node example is my node, this is the script that I'm using.

Download this script
http://pastebin.com/wKytLZmc

Put it anywhere on your server and change the RPCUSER/PASS, NODEADDR and BITCOINADDR.

Run the script to update every time. You can also use it to create a chron job.

To run the script, after editing the values above, put it anywhere and type:
python btc-update.py

If it just returns, that means it works :)

Note: If you get an error, you’ll need to install BitcoinRPC for the script to work.
Go here: https://github.com/jgarzik/python-bitcoinrpc
Follow Jeffs simple instructions. Once BitcoinRPC is installed, run the node script again and it will update!

Good luck!

Comment: I already tried this.. but I failed at installing BitcoinRPC on windows7.

But I think I got it anyway .. http://wiencloud.tk/bitcoin-node

I also made http://btcaudio.tk/live :)

Thanks anyway!

Comment: This is pretty cool:  btcaudio.tk/live can you share the script? Also how did you solve the windows7 issue?

Comment: I didn't install BitcoinRPC .. I just used jsonRPCphp (jsonRPCClient.php) to connect to my bitcoin-node and get the connections, difficulty and blocks. [no python-script used]
you can download the live-script here: http://btcaudio.tk/download